# Playing the audio received from recordRTC websocket client in jetty websocket server

Tags: java, audio, websocket, jetty, recordrtc

How can I play the audio that jetty websocket server shows as bytes in:

```
@Override
public void onWebSocketBinary(byte[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}
```

The audio is received from a websocket client that's using RecordRTC library to capture and encode the audio and is sending it via html5 websocket.

The audio is going to be played on the server-side.

Comment: You obviously need some js library that does that. something like https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи The audio is supposed to be played on the server-side.

Comment: How is that relevant? In that case it would be Java or C/C++ (using JNI) library to play that data.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html